# How to fix 400 Bad request on fetch method POST

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, bad-request

I'am trying to get an acces token from an api, but i get a bad request and tried a lot but can't get it working. This is my code:

```
getOAuthToken() { 
  var data = {
    code: "Wyvo!IAAAABUOiCSXt55U2Ci5yBAhC5_PknZohouEWfxjEXNYnusigQEAAAELnlVYlwPBOa3i1fO7TgqKMQF-llVR16WPRxtatx8BhJRa0H_vaUHCyhd5fJPUXOTdzxu7Vi6I7zQCdEywI3CWHjXomQh5TTfKCJqtwKoq1jyfithm-lq7yLbXUjj3oXbBg8aq3jPJkEDtLNvLFhXhAqQJzDPlxvDTTC4XP-44xpPsFjLLV6_BynZh9sPCgtexgEJCgrN8k_AEhp5D0wTsgnnotvSSiqQnJ9Km-U70aXWgpHuYoyMfwS6lk2BSOn7vMz035jednjkXehSygvSLJYLsu6t-B5td2nO-hzKY0IoDw2aA56FaCjIcs7bAm9O79agZii1XT7K-M_1_g47d5ZhgAHYqsQ1fmXb8MutVAtCQF5uRAajeVm-bhAZ0-y_vdlgD3gQ5wgiShxV56bZU4JRfrOloiODvpRWQep-6N2Fwon3__zuV5ICUkEiS_SOnRkEBfWfMSCeFXVD7jPmdVwd8pt-JxCi0FWH9yRja0naLX_9nJDn02oY2UC-GY64",
    redirect_uri: "https://www.mycompany.com/myapplication",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: "myClieentId",
    client_secret: "MyClieentSecret"
  }
  var dataString = "code=Wyvo!IAAAABUOiCSXt55U2Ci5yBAhC5_PknZohouEWfxjEXNYnusigQEAAAELnlVYlwPBOa3i1fO7TgqKMQF-llVR16WPRxtatx8BhJRa0H_vaUHCyhd5fJPUXOTdzxu7Vi6I7zQCdEywI3CWHjXomQh5TTfKCJqtwKoq1jyfithm-lq7yLbXUjj3oXbBg8aq3jPJkEDtLNvLFhXhAqQJzDPlxvDTTC4XP-44xpPsFjLLV6_BynZh9sPCgtexgEJCgrN8k_AEhp5D0wTsgnnotvSSiqQnJ9Km-U70aXWgpHuYoyMfwS6lk2BSOn7vMz035jednjkXehSygvSLJYLsu6t-B5td2nO-hzKY0IoDw2aA56FaCjIcs7bAm9O79agZii1XT7K-M_1_g47d5ZhgAHYqsQ1fmXb8MutVAtCQF5uRAajeVm-bhAZ0-y_vdlgD3gQ5wgiShxV56bZU4JRfrOloiODvpRWQep-6N2Fwon3__zuV5ICUkEiS_SOnRkEBfWfMSCeFXVD7jPmdVwd8pt-JxCi0FWH9yRja0naLX_9nJDn02oY2UC-GY64&redirect_uri=https://www.mycompany.com/myapplication&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecret"
  const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  const url = "https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token?"
  fetch(proxyUrl + url, {
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataString)
  }).then(function(resp) { 
    console.log(resp);
  })
},
```

I've tried it with data and a dataString. The documentation of the api says: Post data should be x-www-form-urlencoded. But i don't know if i am doing that right.
Please can someone help mee i am really stuck on this :)

Comment: Looks like you are going about this the wrong way right from the get-go. A request like this should not be made from the client side to begin with. Your client secret is called a _secret_ for a reason, it should never be exposed in (public) client-side code. And the fact that you are using a CORS proxy here, presumably because the actual API is not CORS-enabled in the first place, should also be a strong indicator, that how you are trying to do this, is not the correct way. Such an (OAuth?) code-for-token exchange should happen on the server side.

Comment: CBroe thnx for yoou comment this is the documentation: POST ../api/oauth2/token with post data:
(Post data should be x-www-form-urlencoded)

{
   code: “XTzM!IAAAACbPTzQJXwFhM”,
   redirect_uri: https://www.mycompany.com/myapplication
   grant_type: “authorization_code”,
   client_id: “b81cc4de-d192-400e-bcb4-09254394c52a”,
   client_secret: “n3G7KAhcv8OH”
}

You receive the following response:
{
   access_token: “AAEAAGxWulSxg7ZT-MPQMWOqQmssMzGa…”,
   token_type: “Bearer”,
   expires_in: 600,
   refresh_token: “Gcp7!IAAAABh4eI8DgkxRyGGyHPLLOz3y9Ss…”
}

Comment: soo this is right way i think

Comment: Just because the documentation shows what kind of request to make, does not mean that you _should_ be making such requests from just anywhere. Can you link to that documentation?

Comment: yes i can here is a link: https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-oauth-eol-oauth-devstep3

Comment: https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-oauth-eol-oauth-dev-authorization: _“The authorization code grant type can be used by **confidential clients that can protect their client secrets**, like web applications executing on a web server that has a secure channel with the authorization server.”_ - you are not a “confidential client”, if you expose your client secret in publicly available client-side code. You either _need_ to do this on the server, or use a different grant type to begin with.

Comment: aha ookee thank you very much for the information, but i don't know how to fix this so can you push me a little to the right direction?

Comment: I don’t know what exactly you expect to be “pushed” towards here now. If you want to handle this using purely client-side code - then you need to use the implicit grant type, then anything related to the request attempt above is not relevant any more to begin with. And if you want to keep doing it this way, but on the server side - then start writing the code to make such a request from there (we don’t know what languages you’d be using on the server side yet.)

Comment: You explicitly quoted the `x-www-form-urlencoded` part from the docs, yet what you _tried_ to send, was JSON - so that doesn’t match to begin with.

Comment: aha but how can i do it without json then? just data: dataString?

Comment: With the code above, you should not do _anything_, is that still not clear by now?

Comment: oh aha but how can i do it then? i don't understand it ;(

Comment: do you have a turtorial for me wich can explain how to achievee the thing dat i want or?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources such as tutorials, is considered off-topic here to begin with. Plus, you have still not lost one word about which server-side languages you might have available for this … The documentation shows you _what_ request you have to make; and _how_ to make it, in the language of your choosing, is something you need to go and research/read up on a bit now first of all. We can try and help you, if you still struggle with that attempt then.

Comment: oke thank yoo very much i dont know much about server side stuff but i will look for it thank you!